# Window function after Fast Fourier Transform

Tags: fft, window-functions

Hi this is open for discussion since I am doing a capstone project. So I am working with a Raspberry Pi4 and we have a piezoelectric sensor hooked up and and LCD screen as well. My team is recording voltages after a playing an instrument and we used the guitar for this. So I have data that we recorded. My question is... do i need to perform a fast Fourier transform on that data first and then do a window function or can i just simply use a window function if i want my data to have better noise measurements? Our project is coded in python and I've been looking at python code for FFT and window functions.

Just been looking online sources for this and I am not sure how i can apply this to my application since I've never done this before.

Comment: a Fourier Transform ( FFT ) is fed a time series array and responds with that same data in frequency domain representation ... if you only pass in a portion of your source time series data (only a window of data points or samples) the resulting freq domain data is specific to only that stretch of time in defined window which is great if you are interested in capturing changes only in that stretch of time yet the smaller the window means the bigger the freq increment in between each element of the freq domain result ... be aware         `incr_freq = sample_rate / num_samples`

Comment: “i want my data to have better noise measurements” What does this mean? Are you measuring the amount of noise in your data, and you’re asking how to get better measurements? Please [edit] your post to clarify what you want to accomplish, what you have attempted so far, why that is not sufficient, and what you’d like our answer to tell you.